# How to detect history change action (back, forward, etc) in react-router-dom v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

All I could find concerning listening to the location change is a code like:

```
const location = useLocation();
useEffect(() => {}, [location]);
```

But the issue I'm trying to solve is to understand whether the user went back or forward on the page, which the location object doesn't provide by itself.

My business requirement is to log out the user when they press "back" and the "back" page was a log in page which successfully logged the user in. I solved flagging the location via `location.state` to understand whether it's a post-successful-login route. Now I want to listen to the "back" action in the browser and emit the `logout` flow based on `location.state`.
If you have a better solution I'm all ears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to know *how* a user got to the current page then `react-router-dom@6` has a [`useNavigationType`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigation-type) hook that returns the type of navigation.

[useNavigationType](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigation-type)

> ```
> declare function useNavigationType(): NavigationType;
>
> type NavigationType = "POP" | "PUSH" | "REPLACE";
> ```

Example:

```
import { NavigationType, useNavigationType } from 'reat-router-dom';

...

const navigationType = useNavigationType();

...

switch (navigationType) {
  case NavigationType.POP:
    // back navigation

  case NavigationType.PUSH:
    // forward navigation

  case NavigationType.REPLACE:
    // redirection

  default:
    // ignore
}
```

Example:

```
import {
  NavigationType,
  useLocation,
  useNavigationType.
} from 'reat-router-dom';

...

const navigationType = useNavigationType();
const location = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
  if (location.pathname === "/login" && navigationType === NavigationType.POP) {
    // dispatch logout action
  }
}, [location, navigationType]);
```

If you want to couple listening for navigation actions ***and*** calling a callback then consider something like this [answer](/a/71399121/8690857).